# Copy rows conditionally to another sheet and removing them once row has been updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has a checklist that's to be filled out 60, 30, and 1 day before an event.  The sheets are called "60-Day","30-Day", and "Kickoff."  I'm trying to get rows that haven't been checked off to be automatically added to the next sheet (so any unchecked rows on "60-day" get appended to "30-day", and from "30-day" to "kickoff"--also, by "checked off" I mean that an "x" is entered into a cell).  I've got a pretty good start on the code, but I must be doing something wrong - cause it doesn't seem to do anything (forgive my javascript ignorance, my foray into coding started last week with codecademy and a whole lot of browsing on these forums).  I feel like there are some pretty basic things that I'm probably missing and would welcome whatever help I can get.  Here's what I've got...

```
function onEdit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = ss.getActiveCell();
var i = 4;//have this number be your first row of data

  if(r.getColumn()===5){ // this indicates the column that, if left blank, will mean the row should be copied to the next sheet

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="60-Day"){

      var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("60-Day");
      var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("30-Day");
      var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

      while(i<=last_row){

        if(source_sheet.getValue("E"+i)!="x"){

          var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6); // indicate the columns you'd like to copy
          var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1,2,1,6); // indicate the columns where you'd like to paste
          source_range.copyTo(target_range);
          i++;
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }else{
        i++;
        }
      }
};
    else if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="30-Day"){
      var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("30-Day");
      var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kickoff");
      var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

      while(i<=last_row){

        if(ss.getValue("E"+i)!="x"){

           var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6);//indicate the columns you'd like to copy
          var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1,2,1,6);//indicate the columns where you'd like to paste
          source_range.copyTo(target_range);
          i++;
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }else{
        i++;
        }
      };
    }
}
}
```

So that's that -- here's where I run into more trouble though.  If a row has been pushed to the target sheet and gets checked off on the target sheet, I'd like it to disappear from the target sheet AND I'd like the the original row in the source sheet to now show that it has been checked off.  Also, if a previously blank row gets checked off on the source sheet, I'd like the copy that had been pushed to the target sheet to disappear.  This is where I start to get pretty lost.  How would I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll want the changes in this...

```
function onEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  var i = 4;//have this number be your first row of data

  if(r.getColumn()===5){ // this indicates the column that, if left blank, will mean the row should be copied to the next sheet

    if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="60-Day"){

      var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("60-Day");
      var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("30-Day");
      var source_last_row = source_sheet.getLastRow();
      var target_last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;  

      while(i<=source_last_row){

        if(source_sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue() !="x"){

          var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6); // indicate the columns you'd like to copy
          var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(target_last_row,2,1,6); // indicate the columns where you'd like to paste
          source_range.copyTo(target_range);
          //var new_last_row = target_last_row - 1;
          source_sheet.deleteRow(i);  // delete source row after copy
          i++;
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          target_sheet.getRange('E'+target_last_row).setValue('x');  // insert 'x' back into target
        }else{
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="30-Day"){
      var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("30-Day");
      var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kickoff");
      var source_last_row = source_sheet.getLastRow();
      var target_last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;  

      while(i<=source_last_row){

        if(source_sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue() !="x"){

          var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(i,2,1,6);//indicate the columns you'd like to copy
          var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(target_last_row,2,1,6);//indicate the columns where you'd like to paste
          source_range.copyTo(target_range);
          //var new_last_row = target_last_row - 1;

          source_sheet.deleteRow(i);  // delete source row after copy
          i++;
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          target_sheet.getRange('E'+target_last_row).setValue('x');  // insert 'x' back into target
        }else{
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Bryan!  Thanks for the help on this.  For some reason, it didn't seem to work.  Regardless, I'm realizing that I didn't really explain myself well.  I'd ideally like the item to stay on both the original sheet and the sheet that it's copied to, and if it gets checked off in either location, I'd like the original to update and the copy to disappear.  I'm also rethinking the whole onEdit trigger for this.  I'm now going to have the script be user-launchable from a menu.

Comment: If you want them removed on all sheets, you'll have to search for a value in each row that matches with the row you're checking off.

Comment: What I ended up doing was writing 4 different functions (each launchable from the menu), one that moved info from the 60-day to the 30-day, one that moved info from the 30-day to the kickoff, one that reset the 30-day, and one that reset the kickoff.  I had to resort to some hardcoding, and the script is slow since it goes through every line, but it works.  It requires a little more vigilance on the part of the user than I would like, but will work ok.